# How to change a two word attribute separated by dash?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I change the two word attribute in html **with JavaScript?**
Example: There is an example HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="randomscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="mywords" aria-label="Yellow">Words</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: `aria-label` can be changed to any two word attribute (separated by dash) that fits in that context.

Now, moving on to the JS

```
document.querySelector("#mywords h1").aria-label = "Blue";
```

But that doesn't seem to work, as the `aria-label` is still `Yellow`!

How might I do this?
Thanks.

**EDIT:** According to my text editor, the `aria` turns blue, the `-` turns red, but the `label` stays white. This suggests that the dash or what's after the dash is causing the problem.

Comment: The dash is a subtraction operator

Comment: Next time, please do a search before asking. Googling for _"JavaScript set attribute"_ would have given you plenty of answers.

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead...

```
document.querySelector("#mywords h1").setAttribute("aria-label", "Blue");
```

[Javascript setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Answer (score -2):

Or with jquery:

```
$("#mywords h1").attr("aria-label", "Blue");
```

Edit: My bad, didn't notice you wanted only javascript.